# FluxBB vs PunBB

Tags: php, forums, punbb

It's a bit of a soap opera but apparently FluxBB forked from PunBB after PunBB was acquired by a commercial entity. Does anyone have any solid opinions on which is currently better and which has a brighter outlook? I generally prefer leaner software with only the core features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- PunBB 1.2 and FluxBB 1.2 branches are essentially identical.
- FluxBB 1.3 shouldn't be used because development on it has stopped.
- FluxBB 1.4 is a crazy extension of FluxBB 1.2 and is not well-tested and conditioned. Do not use.

I recommend the 1.2 branch of either version, as they are identical, mature and well-tested. Your decision should be based on the activity of the two websites. However keep in mind that in the later versions of the 1.2 branch the bugs were posted on the FluxBB forum, and PunBB incorporated them into their branch.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be exactly what you are looking for but [Mini BB](http://www.minibb.com/) is a pretty lean and stripped to the core (pretty much). With add-on packs to add more functionality.
If that isn't quite what you are after then i would say that Flux BB would be the better of the two choices, especially if you were able to add further modifications as needed further down the road.